# Looking for programs on audio tape/cassette containing programs for Sinclair ZX80 PC?

Tags: z80, sinclair

OK, so back before ice age, I recall having a Sinclair ZX80 PC (with TV as a display, and a cassette tape player as storage device).

Obviously, the programs on cassette tapes made a very distinct sound (er... noise) when playing the tape... I was wondering if someone still had those tapes?

The reason (and the reason this Q is programming related) is that IIRC different languages made somewhat different pitched noises, but I would like to run the tape and listen myself to confirm if that was really the case...

Comment: @Pax - looks like we were both right. The PC was called ZX... yet the CPU was Z80 :)

Comment: I figured you meant zx80 since Clive came out with it, the zx81, the Spectrum and the QL (IIRC - it's been a while). The 80 and 81 were both z80 CPUs, not sure about the other two.

Comment: It's been like 20 years ago, and my Dad actually built it from parts somewhat illegally smuggled into USSR - at this point not sure if it was xz80 or zx81...

Comment: @DVK I still have a bunch of those (but for ZXS not ZX81) but they are mostly demagnetized ... (I have also few hundreds 5.25" DS/DD which are surprisingly still working) anyway the pitch sounds are dependent on transfered data,cassette player speed and the save/load routine. there are turbo-loaders out there for which the sound is different from standard ROM routines sounds. You can also for starters simply type save command in basic into any emulator with proper sound output ... or do it on the real HW :)

Comment: I'm currently making a ZX80 games collection on cassette, along with a collection of games for the Commodore PET and ZX81 - twitter me @YearOfCodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know these come up on auction sites like Ebay quite frequently - if you want to buy them yourself. If you get someone else who owns one to listen then you are going to get their subjective opinion :)

In any case, the language used to save it would be the secondary cause of the pitch changes - it will be related to the data. IOW you could probably create a straight binary data file that sounded very similar to a BASIC program (the BASIC would have been saved as text, as it is interpreted).

Comment: In fact the ZX80's BASIC, while interpreted, was not all text. Keywords were not typed in; they were entered as tokens (i.e. in the keyword mode you would press `G` and GOTO would appear). Entering `GOTO` would do nothing. The character set wasn't ASCII, so all regular printable characters were in the range 0-63 and all the symbols and keywords were 213-255.

Comment: Cool (and a bit different). My background was on Apples, the BASIC programs were tokenised when you ran them.

Comment: And with a whopping 1K of RAM shared between code and video, there wasn't much space. In fast the video memory was like a file, each line taking up only what it needed with CR characters. It was fun to watch the end of the video screen gradually disappear one character at a time as you used more memory :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have the tapes but they've been stored in the garage at my parents' house and the last thirty years hasn't been kind to them.

You can get images here though: http://www.zx81.nl/dload  if that's any use. Perhaps there is a tool out there for converting from the bytes back to the audio ;)

Edit: Perhaps here: http://ldesoras.free.fr/prod.html#src_ay3hacking

Comment: Ah your post has got me all nostalgic for the heady days of Sinclair computing. And especially the games I thought so highly of as a ten year old... Remember 3D Monster Maze? 3D Defender? Ask a coder to write a playable 3D arcade game in 16K of shared memory nowadays and they'll probably look at you like you're some kind of crazy :-)

Answer (score 2):

On the ZX80, ZX81 and ZX Spectrum, tape output is achieved by the CPU toggling the output line level between a high state and a low state. Input is achieved by having the CPU watch an input line level. The very low level of operation was one of Sir Clive's cost-saving measures; rival machines like the BBC Micro had dedicated hardware for serialisation and deserialisation of data, so the CPU would just say "output 0xfe" and then the hardware would make the relevant noises and raise an interrupt when it was ready for the next byte. The BBC Micro specifically implements the [Kansas City Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_City_Standard), whereas the Sinclair machines in every instance use whatever adhoc format best fitted the constraints of the machine.

The effect of that is that while almost every other machine that uses tape has tape output that sounds much the same from one program to the next by necessity, programs on a Sinclair machine could choose to use whatever encoding they wanted, which is the principle around which a thousand speed loaders were written. It's therefore not impossible that different programs would output distinctively different sounds. Some even used the symmetry between the tape input and output to do crude digital sampling, editing and playback, though they were never more than novelties for obvious reasons.

That being said, the base units of the ZX80 and ZX81 contained just 1kb RAM so it's quite likely that programmers would just use the ROM routines for reading and writing data, due to space constraints if nothing else. Then the sound differences would just be on account of characteristic data, as suggested by slugster.

Answer (score 0):

I know the threads old but... I was playing about with something similar last night and I've got a wav of an old zx81 game if you're still interested? pm me and I'll post it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like http://www.wintzx.fr/ or pick something from http://www.worldofspectrum.org/utilities.html#tzxtools to convert an emulator file to an audio file and then you can just play it on your PC. Some tools also allow you to play the file directly. Emulator files can be found at http://www.zx81.nl/files.html and many other places.